# Extracting computed values from the GARCH Bootstrap Forecast from the rugarch package in R

Tags: r, r-s4

This is a rather basic question. I used the 'ugarchboot()' function from the '[rugarch](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rugarch/rugarch.pdf)' package to compute a 'GARCH Bootstrap Forecast' for a time series, as:

```
data(sp500ret)
model.garch = ugarchspec(mean.model=list(armaOrder=c(2,1)),variance.model=list(model = "sGARCH"),distribution.model = "norm")
gfit.ru <- ugarchfit(model.garch, sp500ret)
sim <- ugarchforecast(gfit.ru, n.ahead=50)
boot = ugarchboot(gfit.ru, method = c("Partial", "Full")[1], n.ahead = 500, n.bootpred = 500)
show(boot)

*-----------------------------------*
*     GARCH Bootstrap Forecast      *
*-----------------------------------*
Model : sGARCH
n.ahead : 500
Bootstrap method:  partial
Date (T[0]): 2009-01-30

Series (summary):
           min      q.25      mean     q.75      max forecast[analytic]
t+1  -0.110364 -0.012120  0.000062 0.015208 0.078147           0.001151
t+2  -0.152481 -0.013164 -0.000911 0.013793 0.081966           0.001646
t+3  -0.087277 -0.011170  0.000648 0.014108 0.080913           0.001431
t+4  -0.139871 -0.013395 -0.000192 0.015223 0.079184           0.001241
t+5  -0.130759 -0.011849  0.001213 0.015227 0.067346           0.001090
t+6  -0.098652 -0.012557 -0.001205 0.011462 0.098411           0.000971
t+7  -0.166129 -0.010836  0.000816 0.014676 0.067782           0.000877
t+8  -0.159448 -0.011807 -0.000003 0.014219 0.148961           0.000803
t+9  -0.096594 -0.013533 -0.000389 0.012203 0.087792           0.000744
t+10 -0.074158 -0.009883  0.001997 0.013986 0.131996           0.000698
.....................

Sigma (summary):
          min    q0.25     mean    q0.75      max forecast[analytic]
t+1  0.024891 0.024891 0.024891 0.024891 0.024891           0.024891
t+2  0.023712 0.023780 0.024813 0.025114 0.040604           0.024827
t+3  0.022592 0.023017 0.024702 0.025533 0.051992           0.024764
t+4  0.021568 0.022463 0.024458 0.025284 0.050419           0.024701
t+5  0.020639 0.022066 0.024362 0.025503 0.064920           0.024638
t+6  0.019674 0.021694 0.024236 0.025570 0.074341           0.024575
t+7  0.018936 0.021233 0.024098 0.025608 0.070848           0.024513
t+8  0.018287 0.020838 0.023830 0.025387 0.067688           0.024451
t+9  0.017592 0.020403 0.023678 0.025444 0.076089           0.024389
t+10 0.016920 0.020272 0.023570 0.025579 0.073726           0.024328
```

Everything worked fine, but I am having a hard time finding the location of the 'min', 'q.25', 'mean', 'q.75' and 'max' values stored in 'boot' (type 'S4' object). Can anyone show me how to locate those results? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one was pretty tricky. I had to refer to the [source code](https://github.com/cran/rugarch/blob/master/R/rugarch-methods.R).

There is a custom `as.data.frame` method, so you can do this for the series:

```
t(as.data.frame(boot, which = "series", type = "summary"))
          min     q.25      mean    q.75    max
t+1   -0.1021 -0.01521 -9.76e-04 0.01590 0.0653
t+2   -0.0710 -0.01388  1.84e-03 0.01883 0.0818
t+3   -0.2734 -0.01168  1.43e-03 0.01664 0.0885
t+4   -0.1688 -0.01352 -4.43e-04 0.01434 0.0891
t+5   -0.1081 -0.01087  3.11e-04 0.01397 0.1013
# ... and 495 more rows.
```

And this for the sigma:

```
t(as.data.frame(boot, which = "sigma", type = "summary"))
          min   q0.25   mean  q0.75    max
t+1   0.02485 0.02485 0.0249 0.0249 0.0249
t+2   0.02367 0.02375 0.0247 0.0251 0.0387
t+3   0.02255 0.02310 0.0247 0.0255 0.0414
t+4   0.02153 0.02254 0.0247 0.0259 0.0846
t+5   0.02061 0.02216 0.0246 0.0260 0.0807
# ... and 495 more rows.
```

Comment: Ah...! The package internally computes a summary of the results based on 'boot@fseries' and 'boot@fsigma'---thanks, @Ian!

Comment: I typically just check all of the slots in an unfamiliar S4 object with `slotnames` and then using the `@` operator. But in this case I had to go find the `show` method, which in turn lead me to the `as.data.frame` method. That's S4 for you...